# Hash function to obtain a limited length result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I need to hash a number (about 22 digits) and the result length must be less than 12 characters. It can be a number or a mix of characters, and must be unique. (The number entered will be unique too).

For example, if the number entered is 000000000000000000001, the result should be something like 2s5As5A62s.

I looked at the typicals, like MD5, SHA-1, etc., but they give high length results.

Comment: A Hash, by definition, won't be unique.  Imagine saying, "If I give you 8 unique numbers between 1 and 10, give me 8 unique hashes between 1 and 5".  It's strictly impossible.

Comment: Keerl has 12 chars of hash to work with, so he *can* insert 4.7^21 unique entries. I'd say that, for all intents and purposes, that's a fairly reasonably expectation.

Comment: A hash, by definition, results in less possibilities/choices than the original unhashed value.  If it didn't there wouldn't be any reason to hash it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your question is that the input is larger than the output and unique. If you're expecting a unique output as well, it won't happen. The reason behind this that if you have an input space of say 22 numeric digits (10^22 possibilities) and an output space of hexadecimal digits with a length of 11 digits (16^11 possibilities), you end up with more input possibilities than output possibilities.

The graph below shows that you would need a an output space of 19 hexadecimal digits and a perfect one-to-one function, otherwise you will have collisions pretty often (more than 50% of the time). I assume this is something you do not want, but you did not specify.

[image]

Since what you want cannot be done, I would suggest rethinking your design or using a checksum such as the [cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) (CRC). CRC-64 will produce a 64 bit output and when encoded with any [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) algorithm, will give you something along the lines of what you want. This does not provide cryptographic strength like SHA-1, so it should never be used in anything related to information security.

However, if you were able to change your criteria to allow for long hash outputs, then I would strongly suggest you look at [SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), as it will provide high quality outputs with an extremely low chance of duplication. By a low chance I mean that no two inputs have yet been found to equal the same hash in the history of the algorithm.

If both of these suggestions still are not great for you, then your last alternative is probably just going with only base64 on the input data. It will essentially utilize the standard English alphabet in the best way possible to represent your data, thus reducing the number of characters as much as possible while retaining a complete representation of the input data. This is not a hash function, but simply a method for encoding binary data.

Comment: cool! 'By a low chance I mean that no two inputs have yet been found to equal the same hash in the history of the algorithm'

Answer (score 1):

Why not taking MD5 or SHA-N then refactor to BASE64 (or base-whatever) and take only 12 characters of them ?
NB: In all case the hash will NEVER be unique (but can offer low collision probability)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a hash if it has to be unique.

You need about 74 bits to store such a number. If you convert it to base-64 it will be about 12 characters.

Comment: For all practical purposes, any SHA-2 algorithm will offer a unique output for most of its input space. While it is mathematically true that SHA-2 algorithms will not cover its entire output space, no collision has ever been found for any of the algorithms.

Comment: Actually, you need 76.4 bits to store a 22-digit decimal number. log2(10E22 - 1) = 76.4

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: That's ok if *almost* unique is enough. If it has to be absolutely unique, it's not good enough. The collisions exists, so it's just a matter of how long it takes to find one.

Comment: @JimMischel: The number is "about 22 digits", so that's not exact enough to say that it takes exactly 76.4 bits to store it.

Comment: @Guffa The point is, the original poster likely did not mean to take "unique" to that far of an extent. I feel that "mostly unique", given the content of the post, will satisfy their criteria. Also, no collision exists in SHA-512 for numeric strings encoded using UTF-8 for all combinations of such strings with a maximum length of 22 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what your requirement is for the hashing?  Do you need to make sure the result is diverse? (i.e. not 1 = a, 2 = b)

Just thinking out loud, and a little bit laterally, but could you not apply principles of run-length encoding on your number, treating it as data you want to compress.  You could then use the base64 version of your compressed version.

Comment: If the inputs are random, RLE would not work well. Also, the output of the RLE would vary over time and the length would increase with more unique inputs, in the case they are non-random but sequential.